# How to sort a List<DynamicTableEntity> a sealed class

Tags: c#, sorting, azure

I have a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.DynamicTableEntity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.dynamictableentity.aspx) that I need to sort.  Although `List` provides me a `Sort()` method, `DynamicTableEntity` does not have a default comparator.  As it is a `sealed` class, I can't seem to create my own.

I want to sort on DynamicTableEntity.RowKey.

What would be the most efficient way to sort this list?  Should I roll my own sorting method or should I try to use some sort of Linq query, or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Try with extension method will helpfull

Comment: Can't you use the Sort override that takes a `IComparer<T>` or the `Comparison<T>` delegate?
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That sounds familiar.  I'll look into that, not sure how to do it yet, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Sort` override that has the `Comparison<T>` delegate.

Something like this:

```
entities.Sort((x,y) => /*Code to compare your two entities */);
```

Knowing that the delegate should return an `int` with the following rule:

- -1 if the first element should be before second (x < y)
- 0 if they are equal
- 1 if the first element should be after the second (x > y)

The simple types already implement a CompareTo method that you're likely to be able to use.